# Bluetooth keyboards is not switching languages properly

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

I just bought a cheap bluetooth keyboard to use it with my Huawei MediaPad M3 lite (Android 7.0). It works pretty fine but when I tried to change the language it does not work, i.e. it stay on English (US) (and I have Bulgarian too in the virtual keyboard).
Here is how the settings for it looks like:
[image]
The problem is that I cannot add additional layout/language to the Gboard. It only allows me to select just one.

Strangely enough, the BT keyboard have a shortcut for switching layout (blue Fn + space) and when pressed the virtual keyboard switches the layout but the BT keyboard still uses English. 
I want to be able to add Bulgarian language to physical keyboard. How to do it?
Is this problem solvable in Android 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that built-in any Android version so far but you can achieve it easily with a 3rd party software "External Keyboard Helper":

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en_US

It includes support for Bulgarian typewriter and Phonetic layouts.