# How to switch layout (language) of external physical keyboard on ColorOS 12.1?

Tags: external-keyboard, localization, android-12, oppo-coloros

I have a Bluetooth external keyboard with German layout (QWERTZ) that worked well with my old Huawei P10 Lite phone (Android 8.0).
Unfortunately with my current Oppo Android 12 (ColorOS 12.1) phone I have a big problem:

I cannot switch the keyboard layout, that is: Make Android know that the keyboard layout is German.
When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then the layout of the *virtual* keyboard displayed changes, but the keys on the external keyboard "still send the wrong character" (e.g.: I press <kbd>Z</kbd> on the keyoard, but `Y` is entered on the phone).

Did I use the wrong method to change the layout of the external keyboard, or is this some bug?

I see this question is very similar to [Bluetooth keyboards is not switching languages properly](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200692/377587)

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading ColorOS to Android 13 the problem was fixed, meaning:
I was able to select the keyboard layout.

So it seems it was a bug in ColorOS.